# Java Serialization with an Interface

Tags: java, serialization, interface

I am having trouble both writing an object to a file and reading an object from a file in Java. I have to write a method for each within a class that extends an interface that is given to us. My code right now is as follows:

```
package onlineTest;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SystemManager implements Manager, Serializable {

...

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void saveManager(Manager manager, String fileName){

    try{
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        objectOut.writeObject(manager);
        objectOut.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Manager restoreManager(String fileName){

    Manager m = null;
    try{
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        m = (Manager) objectIn.readObject();
        objectIn.close();
        fileIn.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException f){
        f.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return m;

}

}
```

The only part that must remain are the titles of the two methods, anything inside of them can be changed but I cannot change the titles whatsoever. When I try to run this it gives me an error where I write objectOut.writeObject(manager) in the saveManager method but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "it gives me an error" What is the error? Is it runtime or compile time? Please provide the full text of the compilation error or stack trace.

Comment: Does your class implement [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)?

Comment: Does `Manager` extend `Serializable`?

Comment: Manager does not extend Serializable, but I do not believe I am allowed to change it so it does extend Serializable. For the errors, it gives me a NotSerializableException.

Comment: @jblackman76 In that case you need to clarify the question. `Manager` is an interface, and if that interface does not extend `Serializable` you'll have to resort to something really horrible (e.g. call `getClass()` and then use reflection to find out all the fields you need to save).

Comment: How do I go about using getClass?

Comment: So would it work if SystemManager implements Serializable as opposed to the Manager Interface?

Comment: @jblackman76 Yes, it will, but then I'm not sure why the method signature accepts an arbitrary `Manager`.

Comment: I just made SystemManager implement Serializable and added the 
    'private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;'

Comment: I still receive NotSerializableException when I run through the test though. The error occurs at objectOut.writeObject(manager) in the saveManager method.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Manager does not have to extend Serializable, and no reflection is required. The requirement is for the *concrete class* that implements Manager to be Serializable.

Comment: @EJP I now have the class that implements Manager extending Serializable, but I still receive NotSerializableException and WriteAbortedException. Any idea what I could do to fix that?

Comment: @EJP My comment was not particularly clear, but of course I understand that. My point was that if the method is supposed to work for *all* `Manager`s, and there are `Manager`s out there that do not implement `Serializable`, then the OP is going to need to do something other than `writeObject` to save the object.

Answer (score 0):

In order to serialize a class, the Java serialization machinery requires the class to implement `Serializable`.

If your `Manager` class does not implement `Serializable` itself, and cannot be made to do so, you have a few choices with the `saveManager` method, none of which are really obviously best:

- Change the signature of your `saveManager` method to require a `Serializable` subclass of `Manager`, for instance `SystemManager`; however, this is a bit restrictive, since there may be other implementations of `Manager` that you want to serialize;
- Add a precondition check in `saveManager` to check that `manager instanceof Serializable`. The downside of this is that it's a runtime exception, actually not very different to what you have now;
- You can also define a generic constraint which requires a class to implement both `Manager` and `Serializable`:

  ```
  <M extends Foo & Serializable> void saveManager(M manager, String filename) {
  ```

  However, this requires you to have a reference to the specific subtype of `Manager` to invoke it - e.g. you could if you had a reference to a `SystemManager`, but not if you had a reference to a `Manager` whose value is a `SystemManager`:

  ```
  SystemManager sysMan = ...
  Manager plainMan = sysMan;

  saveManager(sysMan, "filename");  // OK!
  saveManager(plainMan, "filename");  // Error, despite sysMan == plainMan.
  ```

Note also that the fact a class implements `Serializable` is no guarantee that serialization will succeed. The transitive closure of all of the references stored by the class must also implement `Serializable`.

I allude to another solution - making `Manager` extend `Serializable` - but that's not necessarily the right thing to do either. Because of the burden placed on classes that implement `Serializable` - that the transitive closure of their references must also be `Serializable` - there is a heavy burden imposed by adding this interface to base classes. Obviously it is the right thing to do sometimes, but as described in *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 74:

> "Implement `Serializable` judiciously".

There is a very useful JVM flag which identifies the specific class which causes serialization to fail:

```
-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true
```

Yep, serialization in Java is a mess.

Comment: I am unable to change any constraints for the method, and am also unable to change the signature of the method. I attempted adding in the precondition check manager instanceof Serializable but for some reason I still receive a NotSerializableException. I also receive a WriteAbortedException.

Comment: Right - notice what I have said about things that implement `Serializable` not necessarily being serializable, and how to get additional info about the failure...

Comment: I am not sure how or where to add the JVM flag to identify the specific class causing serialization to fail.

Comment: Somewhere after the `java` and before your main class name/JAR.

Comment: I'm sorry I know this is probably a dumb question, but what do you mean after the java?

Comment: You run a Java program on the command line using the command `java` command. After the `java` command, e.g. `java -Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true MainClass`.

Comment: Oh ok, I have been running my Java programs with Eclipse where I have been writing my code to this point. I will try using the command line.

Comment: Use your favourite search engine to search for "eclipse set JVM options" to find out how to do it in eclipse.

Comment: I was able to add the JVM flag, but nothing seems to be different when I run my program. It shows me where in my test the project fails, but it is not showing me which class is causing the sterilization failure.